# laravel artisan use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN' infinite loop

Tags: php, laravel, stdin, infinite-loop, laravel-artisan

I am using laravel 5.6 and have the problem, when I use the command "php artisan vendor:publish" in the console, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN'
Which provider or tag's files would you like to publish?
 [0] Publish files from all providers and tags listed below
 [1] Provider: Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5
```

The problem is, that these messages appear infinite, until I close the console or after a long time it kills the process.

I looked for this issue on google, but only found the problem with stdin and the difference is, that the people who had that problem, didn't call artisan in the command line interface, but directly in a php script.

The same problem appears when I use "php artisan migrate"

Comment: Have you altered any files in the vendor folder? Might be worth doing a `composer update` just in case.

Comment: No, not manually.
All changes were made with composer

Comment: If you try running `composer update` and then running the `vendor:publish` command does that make any difference?

Comment: I tried "composer update" several times, unfortunately it doesn't make any difference.
I was using laravel 5.5 before and because the problem appeared, I thought it would be an idea to upgrade laravel to 5.6, but that also didn't make any difference.

Comment: I am just wondering if there is a package you've installed which is causing this. Would you be able to share your `composer show -i` output?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hR8yMw57

Comment: Could you pastebin your composer.json?

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload` beforehand.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fvuvSfNv

Comment: I tried composer dump-autoload before, but it didn't make any difference

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found a solution for the problem:

I had to add the following line to the artisan file (in the laravel directory).

```
define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));
```

Now it works.

It's still strange, because normally artisan should work out-of-the-box, without the need to change anything.

Comment: To avoid issues in all environments you should use `if(! defined('STDIN')) define('STDIN', fopen("php://stdin","r"));`

Comment: I tied this fix but it aint working. It still says use of undefined constsnt STDIN

Comment: If someone is wondering where to put this code, Then `public/index.php` is the place.

Still not sure why it doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: Didn't work with me

Answer (score 15):

I was getting the issue mentioned above while running artisan command to seed the db tables: `Artisan::call('db:seed', [...])` while in production.
Adding the `--force` flag fixed my issue

```
Artisan::call('db:seed', [
   '--force' => true
])
```

Make sure you use `--force` flag if you are in production.

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
if(! defined('STDIN')) define('STDIN', fopen("php://stdin","r"));
```

to your `index.php` file. I tried adding this to `artisan` file but didn't work but placing it in `index.php` did the trick.
My PHP version is v. 7.4 on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by application environment.
Change application env to `local` or add `--force` parameter after artisan command.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is to ensure you are running the correct version of PHP for the version of Laravel.

`php -v` will show the php version

I was surprised to see that for me, the CLI version of PHP (which is what artisan uses) was really old.

I didn't realize my shared host had many different versions of PHP installed.

I was able to run artisan commands by using the command corresponding to the PHP version I needed to use: `php7.1 artisan migrate`